# Solr 4.1 Core Initialization Failure

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, lucene

I have updated my version of Solr from 3.5 to 4.1
I have removed the old war file from my apache tomcat (7) webapps, and deployed the new war file that has been provided in the apache-solr package.

I got the following error upon trying to access solr from the web browser!

I have one core only(dbTrial)

Solr opens but this error appears.

[image]
SolrCore Initialization Failures
dbTrial: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
There are no SolrCores running. 
Using the Solr Admin UI currently requires at least one SolrCore.

Unable to load environment info from null/admin/system?wt=json.
This interface requires that you activate the admin request handlers in all SolrCores by adding the following configuration to your solrconfig.xml:

Can you help me out? I have tried adding the request handler as specified, but it didn't work.

It seems that the new versions of solr need a new format for solrconfig file. can you assist please! thank you!

the log is the following:

```
????? ?????? 21, 2014 9:19:05 ? org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:168)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:657)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:566)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:850)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:534)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:356)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:308)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5281)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:842)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class         'solr.DisMaxRequestHandler'
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:436)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:469)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:540)
at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:154)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.DisMaxRequestHandler
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:420)
... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Solr log for a better error of what the issue is when Solr is starting up - you'll probably have a better error message there than the one you can see in the Admin interface (which is the error triggered when the interface attempts to access the Solr core). The reason why the core or requestHandler isn't loading will be in the log file, and not in the message produced by the UI. Remember that [logging also changed at 4.3](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging), if you've updated to 4.10 (I see that you wrote 4.1, but if you're planning on going the whole way (or meant 4.10) - the logging might have to be configured as well).

You'll also want to consider the ["going from 3 to 4" document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Major+Changes+from+Solr+3+to+Solr+4#MajorChangesfromSolr3toSolr4-ChangestoConsider), that details the changed to the configuration files (as [solrconfig.xml changed a bit](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Major+Changes+from+Solr+3+to+Solr+4#MajorChangesfromSolr3toSolr4-Changestosolrconfig.xml)).

**Update**
The log shows that it's complaining about loading "solr.DisMaxRequestHandler". This has been deprecated for quite some time and has been removed - just use the standard request handler from the example solrconfig.xml instead.

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: i have added the log can you please assist! @MatsLindh